# Is `document.referrer` url-encoded or not?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, url-encoding, referrer

I wrote a small test page to grab `document.referrer` of users with javascript and send it to a simple log server (like `sendReferrer(document.referrer)`).

The referrer Firefox sends is always url-encoded, (eg. 'http://www.google.com/search?q=%C3%9C' when referrer url is www.google.com/search?q=Ü)

But some clients (like IE9 on Win7) sends urls without url-encoding (www.google.com/search?q=Ü)

Is `document.referrer` is url-encoded in all browsers? Is this reliable (part of any standard) or not?

**UPDATE:** In Firefox15/Chrome21 (on ubuntu) document.referrer is url-encoded

Comment: It's not reliable; it can be spoofed or disabled.

Comment: @Pointy I think the quesiton is about the reliability of it being encoded or not.

Comment: @Yoshi be that as it may, it's bad practice to rely on it for any reason in any application. It was a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: Yes to @Yoshi. I mean reliability of encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final answer for this question: `Referer` may/may not be encoded! With my tests some (only some!) IEs send unencoded referrers (I guess it depends on the locale of client system)

Answer (score 6):

document.referrer isn't URL encoded I have recently tested it in all major browsers and it showed to be non encoded in every one of them.

Comment: In some cases, a string that comes from document.referrer, if you put it in a cookie or something could end up encoded. But document.referrer itself is not url encoded.